# How to redirect maven surefire plugins stdout*deferred temp files away from /tmp folder

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

When I run my test suites (using maven test) which includes around 20000 test cases and create test report using maven surefire plugin it creates a massive temp file in **/tmp** **folder** in my linux server. As I found out since maven cannot contain all the output in memory it **buffers** outputs to /tmp folder creating files with pattern of **stdout*deferred**. I want to **redirect** these files created into a different folder. I couldn't find any configurations to do so. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting a different temp directory than the default one. Call maven with the standard JVM system property for tmp dir:

```
mvn -Djava.io.tmpdir=<otherDir> test
```